# Oscilloscope stop getting data

Tags: oscilloscope, datalogger, data-acquisition

I have a Rigol DS1000Z, and I'm using it to sort of log data.  I have a wavelength tunable laser that creates an electrical pulse (start of pulse is start of sweep, end of pulse is end of sweep), and I have an optical power meter which measures the laser power, and gives an electrical signal.

I trigger the oscilloscope off the rising edge of the pulse, and I look at the power meter output in another oscilloscope channel.  I can then see the power vs wavelength measurements on the scope.  Although not a huge issue, I was wondering if it's possible to tell the scope to stop getting data on the falling edge of the pulse, instead of just filling up its memory.

Is this possible?

Comment: A lot of oscopes have a **RUN/STOP** button... Are you talking about something that would stop the real-time reading of the oscope?

Comment: @KingDuken Yes, I'd like the oscilloscope to stop its real-time reading when it detects a falling edge.

Comment: I suggest 'normal' or 'single' trigger setting, with an appropriate shift of the time reference.

Comment: Can you clarify your Q, it sounds as if you would like to abort an acquisition cycle on the falling edge. I don't think a low end rigol will allow that

Comment: @sstobbe  Yes, that's exactly what I'd like to do.  Basically, I want the pulse to 'window' the data, otherwise I have to just do it myself on a computer.

Comment: I've looked into the instructions manual because I've never used this oscope and I agree with what @VladimirCravero said. There is a setting where you can get a single cycle. Look at [this instructions manual](http://www.batronix.com/pdf/Rigol/UserGuide/DS1000Z_UserGuide_EN.pdf) in Chapter 5. It talks about triggering settings.

Comment: @user968243 if there is such a mode I would guess it would be titled along the lines of "Gated Acquisition"

Comment: Yep, gated is the right name, but is only present in high end scopes and used for more complicated stuff. OP just needs to position the edge just before the right border of the screen.

Comment: I just stumbled on this, which I think is what I want: "TimeOut Trigger (Option)
Trigger when the time interval (△T) from when the rising edge (or falling edge) of
the input signal passes through the trigger level to when the neighbouring falling
edge (or rising edge) passes through the trigger level is greater than the timeout
time set, as shown in the figure below".  And I set timeout to ~0s I guess.

Comment: No, timeout trigger is probably not what you want.  Likely you should just determine the maximum ordinary time, and set the timebase and memory depth so that just fits.  In other cases you may be able to trip the run/stop, but it's unclear if this will leave you with any data.

Comment: I think this is probably an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Rather than asking about how you think you should solve a problem, it would be better to actually tell us what you are trying to do. Why do you want the scope to stop on the falling edge?

Answer (score -1):

If you can determine the time between the rise and fall of the pulse, then set the Trigger time Interval to **5% larger than the length** of the pulse.  The accuracy with which you set the Trigger Interval will determine how much additional data will be stored.

Comment: "Trigger Time Interval" is not a normal oscilloscope setting. You'll need to clarify this substantially if you want it to be positively received.

Comment: Yup, you need the advanced trigger module to do this.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The issue has nothing to do with triggering, and everything to do with recording length.